# Checking Oracle Host address for TNS-3505 error

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, tnsnames

I have look everywhere for this issue. And after six hours yesterday and an hour today I decided to break down and ask the good fellows of stack overflow.

I set up Oracle 10.2.0 (which was an uphill battle) and finally got sql loader working, which I need because TOAD takes 15+hours to load 400k records. So my question is not how to resolve this error, I know the error. I have read nearly 4 tutorials on fixing the error. I want to know, since my TOAD is connected to the database just fine, is there a way I can get all the info from TOAD to populate/verify that my TNSNAMES.ora and sqlnet.ora files are correctly configured? I copy and pasted the information but it won't work anyway.

Also, aside from those two files, are there any other issues that could be preventing this, as a bit of background, I had to reinstall oracle 10g because the admin tools were not in place for the sql loader. Since the sql loader runs, I figured the install is just fine. If you need more info from me comment and I will edit.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a tns name you can try connecting using ezconnect:

```
sqlldr username/password@//localhost:1521/orcl
```

If this solves the issue the tns name used could not be resolved properly. As you say you had to reinstall oracle to get the admin tools I suspect you might be looking at the tnsnames.ora file from the wrong oracle home.

Comment: Your guess was close, and led me to find the actual problem, which was that the install created a second "client" which altered my ORACLE_HOME variable to point to the wrong tnsnames.ora file. THANK YOU SO MUCH.